# How to update a node from the node page with javascript in Drupal?

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7

It looks like it is possible using a custom module with a menu callback, and then an ajax callback function from the page. 
But before I waste time exploring, I'm sure someone must have done this before. Any tips?

Is it adequate to just update the node variable and call `field_attach_update()`? And what about security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security:

You can make sure that the menu hook uses the correct permission access

In menu hook:

```
 $items['/ajax/%/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'something',
    'page callback' => 'your_edit_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'node_access',
    'access arguments' => array('update', 1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

function your_edit_callback($node_id){
//something that edits the node here, only user(s) with node_access will be able to get here.
}
```

about node access:
 * In determining access rights for a node, node_access() first checks
 * whether the user has the "bypass node access" permission. Such users have
 * unrestricted access to all nodes. user 1 will always pass this check.

I have personally never used field_attach, but relied on node_save.

```
$node = node_load($node_id);
$node->field_fieldname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = "monkeys";
node_save($node);
```